# What is the difference between SQL and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to databases and I was wondering: What is the difference between *SQL* and *MySQL*?

Comment: SQL is a language, MySQL is a database (a product)...

Comment: If you meant MS-SQL vs MySQL then check the below link: https://www.upwork.com/hiring/data/sql-vs-mysql-which-relational-database-is-right-for-you/

Comment: @Ben, MySQL is not a database. You may have meant that MySQL is a database management system, which naturally manages databases. But more importantly MySQL is also a language, as each DBMS needs to use a specific variant of SQL and MySQL's variant is just called MySQL.

Answer (score 111):

[SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) - Structured Query Language. It is declarative computer language aimed at querying [relational databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system).

[MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) is a relational database - a piece of software optimized for data storage and retrieval. There are many such databases - Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, SQLite and many others are examples of such.

Comment: It would be helpful to indicate what type of procedural language MySQL is using, e.g. SQL Server TSQL, Oracle PL/SQL and so on. Correct me if I bark at the wrong tree =)

Comment: @bonCodigo - I don't see the relevance to the question.

Comment: Laying out definitions or descriptions and referring persons to Wiki or elswehere is totally <b>invalidating</b> them, as if they couldn't go to Wiki or elswehere themselves. w/o a guidance!  
So, I believe this reply is not only out of place but also bad.

Comment: A relational database is what a relational database management system manages. So it's certainly incorrect to say that MySQL is a relational database.

Answer (score 55):

SQL is Structured Query Language

MySQL is a relational database management system.  You can submit SQL queries to the MySQL database to store, retrieve, modify or delete data.

Answer (score 38):

SQL stands for Structured Query Language, and is the basis for which all Relational Database Management Systems allow the user to add, remove, update, or select records. Things like MySQ are the actual Management Systems which allow you to store and retrieve your data, whereas SQL is the actual language to do so.

The basic SQL is somewhat universal - Selects usually look the same, Inserts, Updates, Deletes, etc. Once you get beyond the basics, the commands and abilities of your individual Databases vary, and this is where you get people who are Oracle experts, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.

Basically, MySQL is one of many books holding everything, and SQL is how you go about reading that book.

Answer (score 21):

SQL is the actual language that as defined by the ISO and ANSI. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) is a link to the Wikipedia article. 
MySQL is a specific implementation of this standard. I believe Oracle bought the company that originally developed MySQL. Other companies also have their own implementations of the SQL standard.

Answer (score 18):

SQL stands for Structured Query Language, and it is a programming language designed for querying data from a database. MySQL is a relational database management system, which is a completely different thing.

MySQL is an open-source platform that uses SQL, just like MSSQL, which is Microsoft's product (not open-source) that uses SQL for database management.

Comment: Is it correct to say... what IDLE is to python is what MySQL is to SQL? @MegaMilivoje