# Develop Database Front-End Application

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, ms-access, frontend

I have an SQL database, and I need to develop a front-end application so that users can view the tables in this database and suggest new entries. This application should be online and offline. Should I develop my application using ACCESS or ASP.NET? And where can I find tutorials to help me start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a view for displaying your application
ASP.NET would be more appropriate for that.
You could use PHP or some of the related MVC frameworks of it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm familiar with PHP more than ASP.NET, but what PHP framework do you advise me to use?

Comment: Try Laravel (http://laravel.com/) is new. It has Laracasts videos for learning as well. It's quite similar with Rails. As I understood you need to build your interface (HTML, CSS) and displaying your database through this. I think laravel is a great framework to learn as well. You can even try OctoberCMS which is based on Laravel and developer friendly

Comment: PHP is usually used with MYSQL can I use it with SQL?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840808/what-is-the-difference-between-sql-and-mysql. SQL is language, mySQL is the database