# How does MySQL server retrieve and send data to clients?

Tags: mysql

If I issued: `select * from tuser where name='Bob'` to mysql server. What would mysql server do, retrieve one record and then send it to client immediately or after retrieving bunch of data then sending it together, and going on for the rest of results?

Comment: This is not strictly On Topic for this site. 
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Results are returned back to the client program as the execution proceeds. As rows ‘bubble’ up the execution tree, the top operator is usually tasked with writing these rows into network buffers and sending them to back to the client. The result is not created first into some intermediate storage (memory or disk) and then sent back to the client, instead it is sent back as is being created (as the query executes). Sending the result back to the client is, of course, subject to the network flow control protocol. If the client is not actively consuming the result (eg. by calling SqlDataReader.Read()) then eventually the flow control will have to block the sending side (the query that is being executed) and this in turn will suspend the execution of the query. The query resumes and produces more results (continue iterating the execution plan) as soon as the network flow control relieves the required network resources.

So the results of a query, are sent to the client "as the query executes".
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630346/Understanding-how-SQL-Server-executes-a-query) you can read more about how an SQL server executes queries.

Comment: You do know that you sited sql server here and not mysql? Do these two database engines operate the same in regards to retrieving and sending the data back to the client?  If so please site source? otherwise how is this answer correct?

Comment: SQL (Structured Query Language) is not a database engine. It’s a standard language for accessing and manipulating databases. MySQL is a specific implementation of this standard. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840808/what-is-the-difference-between-sql-and-mysql

Comment: Once again my previous comment still stands. SQL SERVER as in Microsoft SQL server, is a different database engine than MySQL...You are talking about SQL as it relates to the difference in MySQL and T-SQL syntactically in your above comment...I am talking about HOW THE Database ENGINE itself works...some difference can be seen here http://www.noelherrick.com/blog/mysql-vs-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

On the network protocol level the rows are sent to the client one at a time as soon as the server finds/constructs the record - there is no server-side buffering except for the query cache (for subsequent identical queries) and the network I/O buffer (controlled by net_buffer_length configuration parameter, 16K by default). On the client side you might see some buffering depending on what you use for a client and the settings. The native C libmysqlclient has two calls - mysql_use_result() and mysql_store_result(). The first one does buffer, the second one does. Most higher level languages have client APIs that wrap around libmysqlclient and have the options to use either the buffer or unbuffered method.