# SQL Select all rows greater than a value

Tags: mysql

I have a set of rows in a table that each have a unique key that auto-increments every time a new event is created. For example, the first row that has been created has a key of "1", the second row that has been created has a key of "2", and so on.

I would like to select all of the rows in the table that have a key that is greater than a particular value. For example, if I specify the value to be "6", I want to retrieve all of the rows in the table that have a value greater than 6 in their unique key column.

What is the SQL statement for this operation?

Comment: For future reference, you should really show what you have already tried in your question.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Pigeon. I am still learning the conventions of stack overflow question-making. I will most definitely do that for the next question I have. Thank you again for the feedback; I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: All good, we all have to start somewhere. There are people who can be a bit more critical about it though. Did the query I posted help you solve the issue?

Comment: Yes!! It is perfect. And I have bookmarked the links you gave me to use for future use. They are already very helpful.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. Could you please mark my answer as correct then? (click the little tick) :)

Comment: Have you tried something? Have you read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE UniqueKey > 6
```

Replace `Table` with the name of your table, `UniqueKey` with the field you wish to check for and `6` with whatever value you wish to check for.

I would suggest visiting the w3schools website and looking at the SELECT and WHERE clause pages.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: @axiac, I'm sorry but If you're going to make that assertion, then please provide evidence that they "teach incomplete and incorrect information" rather just merely stating it. Besides, I never suggested to the OP that the information was either complete and/or correct. However, they are a good beginning point for people who haven't had much experience with SQL, and judging by the OP's question, he hasn't. Also w3schools is definitely a lot clearer than the documentation you provided, at least for someone who is still new to SQL.

Comment: I quote from the first link you posted: *"The result is stored in a result table, called the result-set."*. Does this look like a correct statement to you? The result is not stored anywhere, it is just sent back to the application that issued the query. And, btw, the documentation I linked to is **the** official documentation.

Comment: I clearly never disputed that fact, I only said that w3schools provides clearer examples for someone with limited experience with SQL. I quote from the documentation you provided, "To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the `result set`, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:" and "With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the `result set`:". Are you saying that the documentation you provided is also incorrect and incomplete?

Comment: I didn't say the official documentation is incorrect or incomplete. Maybe it has some inconsistencies, maybe some information is not up to date but this is normal for a project that is under active development. What I want to stress out is that it's always better to get the information from the source. And the source, for MySQL, is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Comment: @axiac First, I would suggest you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840808/what-is-the-difference-between-sql-and-mysql). SQL and MySQL are definitely not the same thing. Secondly, you are agreeing with me that "maybe some information is not up to date but this is normal for a project that is under active development" such as w3schools. Thirdly, the documentation you provide says pretty much exactly what w3schools says (refer to my earlier comment about `result set`). So why were so quick to downvote my answer then?