# Are SQL queries limited by the DBMS used?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, rdbms

I've seen reading recently to try and understand initially what the difference was between SQL and MySQL, and I encountered a useful quote from another post ["Basically, MySQL is one of many books holding everything, and SQL is how you go about reading that book."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840808/what-is-the-difference-between-sql-and-mysql).

**Depending on the backend used, i.e MySQL vs PostgreSQL. Can a SQL query suddenly not become valid?**

In particular, **relational DBMS vs non-relational DBMS**?

Comment: Can a SQL query suddenly not become valid? Yes - some features may be deprecated and render queries invalid. But It's part of the manufacturers responsibility to notify us of changes when upgrades are released and it's our job to impact asses them and react appropriately. BTW You should not think that queries are portable between various manufacturers products how they implement standards and the (added value) extensions are up to them.

Answer (score 3):

Each database implements its own dialect of the SQL language.  The dialects can vary in simple ways and in fundamental ways.  For instance:

- Functions might have different names (say `len()` vs `length()`).
- Databases might implement not implement some set of functions (such as `row_number()`).
- Databases might not support common table expressions.
- Databases might not support certain functionality, such as `full outer join`.

The list really goes on.  You should think of SQL as a bunch of dialects.  They significantly overlap each other, but each has differences -- something like the dialects of English spoken around the world.

Comment: oh, so you're saying if I write an SQL statement such as. 

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
FULL OUTER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

It may be a valid SQL statement, but may or may not work depending on the DBMS?>

Comment: Full outer join is not an option on mysql.

Comment: @P.Salmon So what you're saying is this query will not work if the backend is using MySQL as there DBMS? That seems quite odd that it can limit SQL queries, i assumed the backend design like these would always concern to allowing all SQL queries but also add there own syntax.

Comment: SQL is just a standard created by ANSI there are multiple standards like SQL-92, SQL-99 and SQL-2003.. Every SQL standard defines it own statements and how they should work.. DBMS devs choose which SQL standard they implement and which SQL statements..  Most DBMS devs also choose to add custom functions/clauses to "extend" the SQL standards. @J.Doe .. Like PostgreSQL supports `RETURING` on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries to make it possible to directy get the record(s) data back without doing a extra select query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland So what you're saying is that I can't learn SQL statements  from, say w3schools, and apply them to any database. I need to know which DBMS they;re using. For example I can't look at this website https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp and apply it to a database which uses MySQL?

Comment: @J.Doe . . . There may be other reasons to not use `w3schools`, but that is a separate issue (and inappropriate for Stack Overflow).  Once you have the key concepts, switching between databases is not very hard; once again, I would use the analogy to English.  The dialects may be different, but once you learn one, understanding another just takes a bit of learning and some getting used to the sounds.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dialects can vary.

There are two reasons:

1. The ISO SQL standard doesn't require to implement all features it defines. Most of the features defined in the SQL standard as so-called [optional features](https://modern-sql.com/standard/levels).
2. Some databases don't even implement the mandatory features or offer their own syntax for features where the SQL standard foresees another solution (maybe for the vendor lock-in).

I'm running a website that aims to shed light into this jungle: https://modern-sql.com/

E.g., one of the most basic features that was already present in SQL-92 (but is still an optional feature) is the `VALUES` clause. You can see how it is (not) supported here:

- https://modern-sql.com/feature/values#compatibility

However, things are getting better, I hope. E.g. MariaDB (not yet mentioned on my site) introduced the [`VALUES` clause in the recent release 10.3](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12172).