# What is the relationship of SQL to other DBMS's?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

From what I learned from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230828/are-sql-queries-limited-by-the-dbms-used/51238599#51238599), SQL queries at limited by the DBMS used. For example, a SQL query using the `full outer join` will not be possible if the DBMS is MySQL. From this, I have a few more questions that I am confused on.

**Why is SQL denoted as the programming language used to retrieve data from a database if it is purely dependent on the DBMS?** **Every definition I see states that SQL is the standard programming language to manipulate data within a database, but as just said this is not always possible.**

**Why is SQL not a valid option to use for such websites as sqlfiddle.com, you can only use a specific DBMS such as MySQL or SQLite?** **Is SQL syntax meant to be valid within all of these options, but some of these options have there own unique syntax too?**

**When I learnt SQL, I found such websites as w3schools very useful, for example, I feel like this is a good starting point to learn the [full outer join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) method. As specified before this is not valid for a database made using MySQL, so what version/DBMS do so many websites that advertise to teach SQL actually teach?**

**Is it correct to refer to SQL as the "major" programming language, and other DBMS kind of like "custom" SQL's, where they take there own syntax, add/remove some features etc. I got this idea from each database creating there own dialect of the SQL language (Stated in my previous post)**

**Is the term SQL injection not fully accurate, lets say for example a website that is vulnerable to specific syntax for the DBMS they used?**

**Should people be writing SQL on there CV, or always write the specifics such as MySQL, Oracle etc..?**

If an explanation is too long, please give a helpful link so I could read it. Been confused over this stuff for a few hours and every webpage I find just restate the same thing that doesn't really fix what I am confused on. I am fully capable of writing SQL code and I have a decent understanding, but these concepts are confusing me. I want to know the full relationship between all these links.

Disclaimer: This is more of a continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230828/are-sql-queries-limited-by-the-dbms-used/51238599#51238599), but I had a bit more to ask and I don't know if StackOverflow gives notifications if I just edit my old post etc

Comment: Please take the tour to understand how the site works. Just one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is an [industry standard specification](https://modern-sql.com/standard) for a query language for relational databases. The standard is not a piece of software, it's just a document.

Each brand of RDBMS is an implementation of the SQL specification. They are free to write their code differently. The implementation details are not dictated by the standard SQL language document.

SQL has another nuance, that there are [levels of compliance](https://modern-sql.com/standard/levels): **entry**, **intermediate**, and **full**. One company can implement the entry-level parts of SQL and claim that they support it. They can pick and choose which features they want to implement from the intermediate and full levels.

There is no brand of SQL database available today that implements all of the features of the SQL specification!

Furthermore, there are many features offered by every brand of RDBMS that are *not* in the specification. Each vendor who implements SQL has ideas about how they want to enhance standard SQL to offer extra value. There are also complementary features that are part of the RDBMS software but have nothing to do with SQL language.

- Storage formats
- Encryption
- Compression
- DBA tools
- GUI administration consoles and query builders
- Client drivers for JDBC, ODBC, Ruby, Python, PHP, Perl, Go, etc.
- Logging
- Monitoring
- Debugging
- Indexes

That's right — the standard SQL specification says nothing about indexes, although every brand of RDBMS support some kind of indexing syntax. But in the specification, indexes are a subject left to the implementor.

You can compare this with a language like C++. The C++ language is also described in an ISO standard, but there are lots of extra features of every C++ compiler that are not described in the standard. The graphical IDE, the debugger, the compiler optimizations, the build tools, the embedded documentation, and so on.

> Is the term SQL injection not fully accurate?

The technique of SQL injection works with any implementation that supports dynamic SQL. That is, parsing SQL at runtime instead of at compile-time. In fact, SQL injection is just one special case of a broader type of security problem called [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection). This applies to languages that are not even SQL. Anything that can parse and execute code at runtime, with functions like `eval()`.

> Should people be writing SQL on there CV, or always write the specifics such as MySQL, Oracle etc..?

Yes, of course. People who use an RDBMS should be specific about which one they have experience with, when they list them on their resume or C.V. Much like an auto mechanic should be clear about which brands of vehicle they have experience repairing. No doubt their skills are pretty transferrable, and this allows them to learn a new brand quickly if they need to.

> what version/DBMS do so many websites that advertise to teach SQL actually teach?

It depends on the site. You can find sites that have tutorials on any of the major brands of RDBMS. You'll have to ask them. I expect the most common ones are Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, and MySQL. Training sites naturally want to appeal to the largest group of potential customers, and those are the most popular RDBMS products.

Comment: another random question. If SQL is a standard, why do some/all  people refer to it as a programming language?

Comment: Do you refer to C++ as a programming language?

Comment: Yes, but you can write statements using it etc. From what I understand here is that all DBMS's just have to adhere to a certain level of the SQL specification and then they can say they support SQL, there is no SQL language that has its own syntax etc. Whereas C++ is a language in itself and adheres to its own syntax different to other languages

Comment: SQL is a [domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) for querying data. It is seldom used on its own, but it was designed to be used within other applications. This may not qualify it as a programming language by your definition. But SQL does have its own syntax.

Comment: Sorry, still kind of fuzzy. Are you saying that since MySQL, Oracle etc all adhere to the SQL specification you're referring to all DBMS's as SQL? Because when you say SQL is a DSL, you're still implying that SQL is a language (For a domain or for general purpuse), but I thought before you said it is an "industry standard specification", a document?

Comment: The ISO SQL specification describes a language. Companies that want to implement the SQL language read the document and treat it as instructions for what language to implement. When they implement software that recognizes SQL syntax according to that document, and executes the queries in a way that matches how document describes they must behave, then they can say they support SQL.